# type error :integer argument expected

Tags: python

I am making a snake game in Python by the help of google ,  but I found some errors which i dont understand why its so happening...my code is

```
import random
import curses

s = curses.initscr()
curses.curs_set(0)
sh, sw = s.getmaxyx()
w = curses.newwin(sh, sw, 0, 0)
w.keypad(1)
w.timeout(100)

snk_x = sw/4
snk_y = sh/2
snake = [
    [snk_y, snk_x],
    [snk_y, snk_x-1],
    [snk_y, snk_x-2]
]

food = [sh/2, sw/2]
w.addch(food[0], food[1], curses.ACS_PI)

key = curses.KEY_RIGHT

while True:
    next_key = w.getch()
    key = key if next_key == -1 else next_key

    if snake[0][0] in [0, sh] or snake[0][1] in [0, sw] or snake[0] in snake[1:]:
        curses.endwin()
        quit()

    new_head = [ snake[0][0], snake[0][1]]

    if key == curses.KEY_DOWN:
        new_head[0] += 1

    if key == curses.KEY_UP:
        new_head[0] -= 1

    if key == curses.KEY_LEFT:
        new_head[1] -= 1

    if key == curses.KEY_RIGHT:
        new_head[1] += 1

    snake.insert(0, new_head)

    if snake[0] == food:
        food = None
        while food is None:
            nf = [
                random.randint(1, sh-1),
                random.randint(1, sw-1)
            ]
            food = nf if nf not in snake else None
        w.addch(food[0], food[1], curses.ACS_PI)
    else:
        tail = snake.pop()
        w.addch(tail[0], tail[1], ' ')
        w.addch(snake[0][0], snake[0][1], curses.ACS_CKBOARD)
```

While running this code I got two errors, i.e.,

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "snakegame.py", line 20, in <module>
w.addch(food[0], food[1], curses.ACS_PI)
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float
```

Comment: What did you think dividing would get you?

Comment: Have you tried `w.addch(int(food[0]), int(food[1]), curses.ACS_PI)` ?

Comment: `while food is None:` will never stop. You need to indent `food = nf if nf not in snake else None`, I suppose.

Comment: @mehrdad-pedramfar   yup, I tried this too... but nothing changed in error .. I am having same problem..

Comment: @mehrdad-pedramfar now there is "TypeError: int() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)

Comment: @user726763 are you sure that you use `(` and `)` correct ?

Comment: what is the value of `sh` ?

Comment: @mehrdad-pedramfar its [0][0] and value of sw is [0][1]

Answer (score 2):

In Python 3 `/` results in floating point results. To get integer results, use integer division `//`.

```
food = [sh // 2, sw // 2]
```

In addition, your `snake` is initialized with floating point numbers. Again, in order to make sure that `snake` contains only integers, do this:

```
snk_x = sw // 4
snk_y = sh // 2
```

After that, you will see a different crash due to `new_head` exceeding `sw` or `sh` (if you leave the snake move by itself without pressing any keys) but this is unrelated to the original issue.

Comment: @user726763 It is due to the same issue but with different variables: `snk_x` and `snk_y`. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

Modified a bit, no error, but food not coming second time.

```
import random
import curses

s = curses.initscr()
curses.curs_set(0)
sh, sw = s.getmaxyx()
w = curses.newwin(sh, sw, 0, 0)
w.keypad(1)
w.timeout(100)

snk_x = sw/4
snk_y = sh/2
snake = [
    [snk_y, snk_x],
    [snk_y, snk_x-1],
    [snk_y, snk_x-2]
]

food = [sh/2, sw/2]
w.addch(int(food[0]), int(food[1]), curses.ACS_PI)

key = curses.KEY_RIGHT

while True:
    next_key = w.getch()
    key = key if next_key == -1 else next_key
    if snake[0][0] in [0, sh] or snake[0][1] in [0, sw] or snake[0] in       snake[1:]:
    curses.endwin()
    quit()

new_head = [snake[0][0], snake[0][1]]

if key == curses.KEY_DOWN:
    new_head[0] += 1
if key == curses.KEY_UP:
    new_head[0] -= 1
if key == curses.KEY_LEFT:
    new_head[1] -= 1
if key == curses.KEY_RIGHT:
    new_head[1] += 1

snake.insert(0, new_head)

if snake[0] == food:
    food = None
    while food is None:
        nf = [
            random.randint(1, sh-1),
            random.randint(1, sw-1)
        ]
        food = nf if nf not in snake else None
    w.addch(int(food[0]), int(food[1]), curses.ACS_PI)
else:
    tail = snake.pop()
    w.addch(int(tail[0]), int(tail[1]), ' ')

w.addch(int(snake[0][0]), int(snake[0][1]), curses.ACS_CKBOARD)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wVzwp.png)

Comment: Please explain your solution.

Comment: The addch function is asking for integer parameter, so i did typecasting by int(parameter). And it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit modified and works fine for me.

```
import random
import curses

s=curses.initscr()
curses.curs_set(0)
sh,sw=s.getmaxyx()
w=curses.newwin(sh,sw,0,0)
w.keypad(1)
w.timeout(100)

snk_x=sw//4
snk_y=sh//2
snake=[
[snk_y,snk_x],
[snk_y,snk_x-1],
[snk_y,snk_x-2]

]

food=([sh//2,sw//2])
w.addch(food[0],food[1],curses.ACS_PI)
key=curses.KEY_RIGHT

while True:
 next_key=w.getch()
 key=key if next_key==-1 else next_key

  if snake [0][0] in [0,sh] or snake [0][1] in [0,sw] or snake[0] in snake [1:]:
    curses.endwin()
    quit()
new_head =[snake[0][0],snake[0][1]]

if key ==curses.KEY_DOWN:
    new_head[0]+=1
if key==curses.KEY_UP:
    new_head[0]-=1
if key==curses.KEY_LEFT:
    new_head[1]-=1
if key==curses.KEY_RIGHT:
    new_head[1]+=1
snake.insert(0,new_head)

if snake[0]==food:
    food=None
    while food is None:
        nf=[
        random.randint(1,sh-1),
        random.randint(1,sw-1)
        ]
        food=nf if nf not in snake else None
    w.addch(food[0],food[1],curses.ACS_PI)
else:
    tail=snake.pop()
    w.addch(tail[0],tail[1],' ')


w.addch(snake[0][0],snake[0][1],curses.ACS_CKBOARD)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine

```
import random
import curses

s = curses.initscr()
curses.curs_set(0)
sh, sw = s.getmaxyx()
w = curses.newwin(sh, sw, 0, 0)
w.keypad(1)
w.timeout(100)

snk_x = int(sw/4)
snk_y = int(sh/2)
snake = [
    [snk_y, snk_x],
    [snk_y, snk_x-1],
    [snk_y, snk_x-2]
]

food = [sh/2, sw/2]
w.addch(int(food[0]), int(food[1]), curses.ACS_PI)

key = curses.KEY_RIGHT

while True:
    next_key = w.getch()
    key = key if next_key == -1 else next_key

    if snake[0][0] in [0, sh] or snake[0][1]  in [0, sw] or snake[0] in snake[1:]:
        curses.endwin()
        quit()

    new_head = [snake[0][0], snake[0][1]]

    if key == curses.KEY_DOWN:
        new_head[0] += 1
    if key == curses.KEY_UP:
        new_head[0] -= 1
    if key == curses.KEY_LEFT:
        new_head[1] -= 1
    if key == curses.KEY_RIGHT:
        new_head[1] += 1

    snake.insert(0, new_head)

    if snake[0] == food:
        food = None
        while food is None:
            nf = [
                random.randint(1, sh-1),
                random.randint(1, sw-1)
            ]
            food = nf if nf not in snake else None
        w.addch(food[0], food[1], curses.ACS_PI)
    else:
        tail = snake.pop()
        w.addch(int(tail[0]), int(tail[1]), ' ')

    w.addch(int(snake[0][0]), int(snake[0][1]), curses.ACS_CKBOARD)
```

Answer (score 0):

Other solutions are over-using int() in more places than needed. You only need to use // integer division in the places I've shown.

Also a bit more fun. Diamond back snake.

```
import random
import curses

s = curses.initscr()
curses.curs_set(0)
sh, sw = s.getmaxyx()
w = curses.newwin(sh, sw, 0, 0)
w.keypad(1)
w.timeout(100)

snk_x = sw//4 # use integer division here
snk_y = sh//2 # use integer division here
snake = [
    [snk_y, snk_x],
    [snk_y, snk_x-1],
    [snk_y, snk_x-2]
]

food = [sh//2, sw//2] # use integer division here
w.addch(food[0], food[1], curses.ACS_PI)

key = curses.KEY_RIGHT

while True:
    next_key = w.getch()
    key = key if next_key == -1 else next_key

    if snake[0][0] in [0, sh] or snake[0][1] in [0, sw] or snake[0] in snake[1:]:
        curses.endwin()
        quit()
    
    new_head = [snake[0][0], snake[0][1]]

    if key == curses.KEY_DOWN:
        new_head[0] += 1
    if key == curses.KEY_UP:
        new_head[0] -= 1
    if key == curses.KEY_LEFT:
        new_head[1] -= 1
    if key == curses.KEY_RIGHT:
        new_head[1] += 1

    w.addch(snake[0][0], snake[0][1], curses.ACS_DIAMOND)
    snake.insert(0, new_head)

    if snake[0] == food:
        food = None
        while food is None:
            nf = [
                random.randint(1, sh-1),
                random.randint(1, sw-1)
            ]
            food = nf if nf not in snake else None
        w.addch(food[0], food[1], curses.ACS_PI)
    else:
        tail = snake.pop()
        w.addch(tail[0], tail[1], ' ')

    w.addch(snake[0][0], snake[0][1], curses. ACS_CKBOARD)
```

Answer (score 0):

use // not / because interpret see your parameter in flote values while you want to insert integer values

```
snk_x = sw//4
snk_y = sh//2
snake = [
    [snk_y, snk_x],
    [snk_y, snk_x-1],
    [snk_y, snk_x-2],]
food = [sh//2, sw//2]
```